# My Ubuntu installation did not result in a dual boot menu option

Tags: dual-boot

I thought that I was installing Ubuntu version 14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso properly on my laptop (created a bootable USB, checked it for errors and found none, and installed it followed the simplest options using the default partitions), but my machine (an ASUS Q302L) starts up without offering the dual boot menu - it only sees Windows (8.1).

Using MiniTool (partition wizard), I can see the new 213 GB Ext4 partition, and a new 5.89 GB partition that I assume is the Linux Swap area. 
My BIOS settings include Launch CSM = Enabled (but I don't know what that does).

Any suggestions as to what I might do to try to get Linux to boot from the installed version, or what to look at to try to determine what went wrong? Failing that, how to uninstall Ubuntu so that I can try it again?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't paste links here from my device. But you may just want to reinstall Grub (ask Google) from your USB or your live CD.
If it doesn't work, maybe your PC is «tattooed», you may want to look for it too.

Comment: Great - I found what looks to be a nice set of instructions on a You Tube video named "Grub Rescue – Complete Re-install of GRUB 2 from Live USB". But meanwhile I found this recommendation from ubuntu, "Normally you install in UEFI mode because Windows is installed in UEFI mode and you want to dual boot" - wish I'd seen that before. I did not do my install in that mode, I just the chose the plain flash drive option. Do you think it would be a good idea to simply try reinstalling ubuntu over my old install, choosing the UEFI mode option?

Comment: I did check out sudo fdisk -l, and got this output (summarized, cannot save screenshot in live session): only 2 disks, the 1st  being /dev/sda, 32 GB, bootable, W95 FAT32 (LBA); the 2nd being /dev/sdb, 500.1 GB, GPT. I see these additional notes: 1) WARNINGL GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on ‘/dev/sdb’! The util fdisk doesn’t support GPT. Use GNU parted. 2) Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Comment: Question - can you tell me - what I see with sudo fdisk -l    ...is the 1st disk my USB and the 2nd disk my PC's hard drive?